# non exclusive pattern matching in Scala possible?

Tags: java, scala, switch-statement, pattern-matching

I was wondering if there is a way for me to 'non exclusively' match certain cases in Scala.
For example in Java I used to code switch cases like this

```
switch(dressing_step){
  case 1:
    System.out.println("put on underpants\n");
  case 2:
    System.out.println("put on jeans\n");
  case 3: 
    System.out.println("put on shoes\n");
  default:
    System.out.println("You're good to go\n");
    break;
}
```

So if I wanted to describe a sequence of actions I could just leave the 'break' keyword et voila, if my dressing_step began at 1 it would automatically run over all the other cases, too.
If I match a step like this in Scala I can only ever match one case at a time. Is there something like a nice pattern, which lets me imitate the switch case behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a catch-all clause at the end:

```
x match {
  case ThingOne => println("thing one")
  case ThingTwo => println("thing two")
  case x => println("unknown: " + x)
}
```

If you don't care about its value, you can replace `x` with `_`:

```
case _ => println("unknown")
```

Comment: Not sure why this got upvoted since it answers a different question! - note the lack of "break" in the OP's question  - the question is about "fall through" from case to case, not about handling the "default" case .

Comment: If ThingOne matches, your code would print "thing one", but then leave the match block instantly wouldnt it?  I was asking for a way in which I can iterate over a few case blocks (like in switch cases without break in Java). 
Maybe I don't get what you are trying to tell me but at the moment I think you might have misunderstood my question?

Comment: @Julian, yes, he has. See the question marked as possible duplicate for an answer to your actual question.

Comment: I already accepted the duplicate mark, thanks for the reference